# How to test Sample Solution from dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dotnetopenauth

I downloaded the latest dotnetopenauth from here https://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth/download?package=DotNetOpenAuth&release=3.4.1

I open the sample solution, now i just want to test "OAuthServiceProvider", how do i do this? it doesn't work.

Project Link: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: Suggest change of question title to "How to test Sample Solution from dotnetopenauth" or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuthServiceProvider sample is designed to work with the OAuthConsumer sample.  But the consumer sample's web.config file needs to be modified to allow for making HTTP requests to localhost if you host it locally.  Then make sure the port numbers line up.  Finally, you have to add your own data to the database in OAuthServiceProvider so that it works meaningfully for you.

Overall, this is one of the worst samples that come with DNOA for purposes of running the sample to see it work.  We need to improve that story.  But it may still be useful to just code review for your own project.

Comment: Very bad sample :-(  I just want to test OAuth but i cant get passed the stupid OpenID part - grrrrr

Answer (score 1):

From the Menu, select the follwong commands in steps

**Step1** build the project: **Build** - > **Build Solution**

**Step2:** Run the project:  **Debug** -> **Start Debugging** / **Start without Debugging**.

Comment: I did this, but it didn't work, error

http://i.imagehost.org/0945/vserror.jpg
----------

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this page on our website which should help you get things sorted out.

**https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/ContributorQuickStart**

**Edit: Fixed link.

Comment: this link is broken 11/2013 ??

Comment: fixed. You know there's always google to help you find things.